# Is there a way to tell the scala compiler not to do a tail call optimization?

Tags: scala

Just for experimentation purpose i would like to stop the compiler from doing a tail call optimization of a function that is tail recursive. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Well, a dirty trick would be to change any recursive call with an assignment to a variable and then return that variable. That should stop the tail-optimization but I am not sure if the compiler will be smart enough to remove the unnecessary assignment.

Answer (score 5):

Try `-g:notailcalls` compiler option [which](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/52cdad95982e0bf05d00a0caaaba7d6d2b490a2d/src/manual/scala/man1/scalac.scala#L118)

> will not perform tail call optimization